# How to unit test a missing browser feature implementation for 100% code coverage?

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm working on a JavaScript Web Audio API library and have multiple tests or normalizations for browser feature implementations eg.

```
try {
  window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
  window.AudioFXGlobal.context = new AudioContext();
} catch (e) {
  AudioFX.error("Web Audio API Error: " + e.message);
}
```

or

```
if (!this.source.start) {
  this.source.start = this.source.noteOn;
}
```

where the corresponding branches are the only code parts that I haven't yet covered by unit test cases. I tried to manually set eg. `window.AudioContext` to `null` for example before reaching the code block, but without luck.

So my question is how to approach the problem or respectively if it even makes sense to try to reach 100% code coverage, with currently residing at 93% according to Istanbul.

Answer (score 0):

SoundJS WebAudioPlugin sets up support for older versions of web audio when it is initialized by creating the latest properties and methods of the api on context using older methods if they don't already exist.  See [WebAudioPlugin._compatibilitySetUp](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/SoundJS/files/soundjs_webaudio_WebAudioPlugin.js.html#l292) for details.

example:
`s.context.createGain = s.context.createGainNode;`

Comment: Thanks for taking time OJay, but your example is 1:1 in my code for the gainNode-creation. My question was more targeted how to furnish test cases so I can deliberately run into errors caused by missing browser implementations through unit testing. The answer is most likely generic and not WebAudio-related at all.